# Predicting y from a log-linear regression

Tags: regression

I was wondering if someone could explain to me the very last step on the right hand slide. Why is do we have a sum rather than a product.

Thank you very much.

[image: Predicting y from a log-linear regression]

Comment: That looks like a typo to me. For $x=\beta=c=0$, the first row equals $1$, while the bottom equals $n+1$, so I don't think it is right.